# TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined)

Tags: typescript, undefined

I am stuck with TypeScript error:

```
Failed to compile.

undefined
TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined):
File name '/path/to/file/MyFileName.types.tsx' differs from already included file name '/path/to/file/myFileName.types.tsx' only in casing.  TS1149
```

Spot the difference in first letter between `myFileName` and `MyFileName`. I have not idea how this happened and I don't know how to fix it. I have never seen this error before.
I am using TypeScript Version 3.5.3. If someone can at least point me into direction what to do, it would be super helpful.

Comment: For a similar issue I had to rm -rf node_modules and then yarn install again. Not quite sure what the issue was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh crap. There was a lowercased import somewhere in my code:

```
import { TSomething } from './myFileName.types'
```

while real file name was uppercased:

```
MyFileName.types.tsx
```

I still don't know why TypeScript compiler didn't tell me where was that.

Answer (score 5):

For my case, I just installed packages with this command

`npm i`

Answer (score 2):

Just run:
"yarn tsc" or npm.
Works!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is probably the craziest error I've ever seen.

#### Context

- vue 2.6.10
- typescript 4.4.3
- Built using webpack via `vue-cli-service build`.

I was getting following error on build:

```
⠼  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                   10:49:11

 error  in [internal]

INTERNAL ERROR(undefined,undefined) Debug Failure.
stack trace:
Error: Debug Failure.
    at /Users/user/path/to/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:19487:89
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at formatStringFromArgs (/Users/user/path/to/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:19487:21)
    at Object.createDetachedDiagnostic (/Users/user/path/to/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:19503:20)
    at parseErrorAtPosition (/Users/user/path/to/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:30898:42)
    at parseErrorAt (/Users/user/path/to/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:30905:13)
    at parseErrorAtCurrentToken (/Users/user/path/to/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:30892:13)
    at parseErrorForInvalidName (/Users/user/path/to/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31130:17)
    at parseErrorForMissingSemicolonAfter (/Users/user/path/to/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31102:21)
    at parseExpressionOrLabeledStatement (/Users/user/path/to/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:34993:21)

 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
```

#### Solution

The error was an **HTML text** in Vue template.

```
<template>
  ...
  Please type "{{ listName }}" to confirm.
  ...
</template>
```

I had to replace the word `type` with something else to fix the TypeScript error:

`Please write "{{ listName }}" to confirm.`

#### Update

After further experimenting, what's causing the issue is the following pattern in HTML text:

```
type "
```

Where anything can be between the double quotes, so `type ""`, `type "hello"`, etc, all cause this error.

Conversely, when I put anything between the `type` and `"`, it builds again, eg `type a "`.